# How to call Component or Service from Controller in Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I want to save region ( property of authenticated User) in a class. Region list is fetched from Database and stored as a property for each User in Spring Controller Class suppose "A".

Now this region property I want to fetch in spring interceptor "B" and want to validate the region for the user which I am getting as a parameter in each http request to that of stored in region property.

I was suggested to use Service or Component to store region list so that Interceptor B and Controller Class A can both use that Service or Component.

Can any one tell me how to use Service or Component in this case.

Answer (score 8):

Your question isn't entirely clear, but I'll try my best.

I think you are saying you want to use the same class in both a Spring MVC HandlerInterceptor as well as a Controller?

You should use Dependency Injection for this:

Annotate the service class with @Service (this lets Spring find your service)

```
@Service
public class MyRegionService...
```

Add component-scanning to your application context configuration (this finds the service)

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.example.yourapp"/>
```

Add the service as a class member wherever you need it, and annotate it with @Autowired (this injects the service)

```
@Controller
public class MyController {

  @Autowired
  MyRegionService myRegionService;
}
```

and

```
public class MyHandlerInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {

  @Autowired
  MyRegionService myRegionService;
}
```